# Error message "sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain: unrecognized message ID 27"

Tags: javascript, applet

I have a application in which we add annotations . Whenever i am trying to add annotation in applet view its not reflection directly . In the console in am getting an error msg. sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain: unrecognized message ID 27
Sometimes annotations reflect straight away but many a times we have to do it 4-5 times ...
Its affecting our application .

earlier we were using document.viewer.ExtQuery js function but now we have changed it to document.viewer.ExtCmd function ...This might be the case....
Please can some suggest a workaround or i have to change some java settings ...Please suggest!